# How to change code from working with .hover() to working with .click() and .hover()

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make this script from just hover to onclick and on hover:

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function () {
    $j(".swatch-anchor").hover(function () {
        var newTitle = $j(this).attr("title");
        $j("#colour-name").html(newTitle);
    },
    function () {
        var swapTitle = $j("#colour-name").html();
        $j(this).attr("title", swapTitle);
        $j("#colour-name").html("");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function () {
    $j(".swatch-anchor").on('click mouseenter',function () {
        var newTitle = $j(this).attr("title");
        $j("#colour-name").html(newTitle);
    });

    $j(".swatch-anchor").on('mouseleave',function () {
        var swapTitle = $j("select-option.selected a").text();
        $j("#colour-name").html("");
    });
});
```

Comment: @anmaree do you want a click? or a mobile touch event maybe. The click on a hover makes not much sense... anyway, the second part (mouseleave ) is the one changing backthe name of the color, if you want the name to be there remove it.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

http://jsfiddle.net/4cPQG/

```
$j(".swatch-anchor")
.on('mousedown mouseover', function () {
    //...
})
.on('mouseup mouseout', function () {
    //...
});
```

Comment: Going to need more than that. hover (on|off) takes two functions, while click only takes 1.

Comment: sorry but that doesn't work. ok i will post more information soon